# SwiftUI: Different alignment behavior of containers in GeometryReader

Tags: ios, swiftui, geometryreader, zstack, swiftui-zstack

A `Text` element inside a `ZStack(alignment: .bottom)` is displayed at the bottom of the container (as expected). Tho, if the same `ZStack` is inside a `GeometryReader`, the alignment does not behave the same anymore.

This code:

```
var body: some View {
  ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
    VStack {
      Text("Outside geo")
    }
  
    GeometryReader { geo in
      ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
        VStack {
          Text("Inside geo")
        }
      }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
  }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
}
```

produces this result:

[image: Result of code]

If I'd want the "inside geo" to be placed at the bottom too, I'd have to add `alignment: .bottom` inside its parent ZStack .frame(...) modifier.

What's the background for this behavior? Why can I use `ZStack(alignment: ...)` in one case, but have to use `ZStack {...}.frame(alignment: ...)` in the other to achieve the same result?

Comment: Instead of writing 1k words... add `.border` modifier to each container and you'll see the reason... (btw GR is a container as well).

Answer (score 0):

It might look strange, but the text "Inside geo" in the `GeometryReader` is correctly aligned at the bottom of the `ZStack` - the problem is that your `ZStack` is not aligned at the bottom of the `GeometryReader`.

The stacks occupy the minimum amount of space necessary, while the `GeometryReader` has the opposite behaviour. So, the `GeometryReader` is aligned at the bottom of your high-level `ZStack` but it occupies the whole screen, while the inner-level `ZStack` is centred inside the `GeometryReader`.

Try putting a `.background(someColor)` on each view and you'll see where they are positioned.

If you want the "Inside geo" to be at the bottom of the screen, you need to tell the `ZStack` to get placed at the bottom with the `alignment` parameter - like this:

```
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            VStack {
                Text("Outside geo")
            }
            
            GeometryReader { geo in
                ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                    VStack {
                        Text("Inside geo")
                    }
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom) // Here you add the alignment parameter
            }

        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

*After experimenting, I now know what **causes** this behavior, still it felt kinda unexpected first.*

When setting the .frame max-size of the ZStack to .infinity (to stretch it out), its "inner size" / **content still stays "hugged"**, rather than stretched out too. Means, the content of a container does not always necessarily use all the space it could.

Take this example:

```
ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
  Color.red
    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
}
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
.background(Color.blue)
```

This produces a whole different placement of the red box than when adding a second view, **that pushes the inner bounds of the container**.

```
ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
  Color.red
    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
  
  Color.clear
    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
}
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
.background(Color.blue)
```

The frame of the clear color now pushes its parents bounds, since its height tries to scale up as much as it can. *A GeometryReader has the same nature, since it always tries to fill its parent.*

Now the red box is not hugged anymore and has all the space (caused by the clear color) to move around freely (to the bottom).

Here are the two results:

[image]

### Conclusio

The `alignment` parameter of `.frame` decides where the hugged "inner frame" of a container is placed inside the full-frame of the container. The `alignment` parameter of a **Container** decides, where its content is placed inside its "inner frame" (which can be hugged).